# Xamarin Facebook.iOS SDK InvalidScope: ids_for_business

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, facebook-sdk-4.x

I'm using pretty much the exact example code that's found on the page for the [Facebook iOS SDK](https://components.xamarin.com/view/facebookios) component.

If I remove the `ids_for_business` it works fine. The thing is, I need either `ids_for_business` or `token_for_business`.

I tested the following using the Facebook Graph API Explorer and it works fine.

```
me?fields=ids_for_business,token_for_business
```

Here's the permissions I'm requesting:

```
List<string> readPermissions = new List<string> { 
     "public_profile","name","email","first_name","last_name", "ids_for_business" };
```

And here's the method I'm calling:

```
private void ShowLogin()
{
    // If was send true to Profile.EnableUpdatesOnAccessTokenChange method
    // this notification will be called after the user is logged in and
    // after the AccessToken is gotten
    Profile.Notifications.ObserveDidChange((sender, e) => {
        if (e.NewProfile == null)
            return;               
    });

    // Set the Read and Publish permissions you want to get
    loginView = new LoginButton(new CGRect(51, Element.Height / 2, 218, 46))
    {
        LoginBehavior = LoginBehavior.Native,
        ReadPermissions = readPermissions.ToArray(),              
    };

    // Handle actions once the user is logged in
    loginView.Completed += (sender, e) => {
        if (e.Error != null)
        {
            // Handle if there was an error
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Facebook Login Failed! {e.Error.DebugDescription}");
            login.FacebookNotAuthenticated();
        }

        if (e.Result.IsCancelled)
        {
            // Handle if the user cancelled the login request
            login.FacebookNotAuthenticated();
        }
        else
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Facebook Login Success!");
    };

    // Handle actions once the user is logged out
    loginView.LoggedOut += (sender, e) => {
        // Handle your logout
    };

    View.AddSubview(loginView);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the documentation: [Permissions Reference - Facebook Login](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/), this lists all permission keys we can require. But I didn't find **ids_for_business** nor **token_for_business**, it's not a legal string on facebook. So it will return invalid scope. Is `business_management` what you need?

Please refer to this documentation to find the corresponding permission string. Moreover notice that only `public_profile`, `user_friends`, and `email` do not require Review, all other permissions do.